# Something strange with IF in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I hava a update sql like below:

```
update saletargets_import_data as st_im left join saletargets as st
on st_im.saletarget_hospital_id=st.saletarget_hospital_id
and st_im.saletarget_product_id=st.saletarget_product_id
set st_im.record_id=if(st.deleted=0 and st.id is not null,st.id,st_im.record_id)
where st_im.import_id=383;
```

it does not affect.which return:
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
and the st_im.record_id dont update

however, when i use like below:

```
update saletargets_import_data as st_im left join saletargets as st
on st_im.saletarget_hospital_id=st.saletarget_hospital_id
and st_im.saletarget_product_id=st.saletarget_product_id
set st_im.record_id=if(st.id is not null,st.id,st_im.record_id)
where st_im.import_id=383 and st.deleted=0;
```

it works, the st_im.record_id update!, but I do not know why…
Clould anyone can figure the difference between these two SQL?

Comment: For people searching in the future, please clarify if this is [tag:mysql] or Microsoft [tag:sql-server]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
update saletargets_import_data as st_im
 left join saletargets as st
  on st_im.saletarget_hospital_id = st.saletarget_hospital_id
 and st_im.saletarget_product_id = st.saletarget_product_id
 and st.deleted = 0
   set st_im.record_id = if(st.id is not null, st.id, st_im.record_id)
 where st_im.import_id = 383
```

The problem is the `LEFT JOIN` , `st.deleted` can be `NULL` , so the condition `if(st.deleted = 0)` will result in `NULL` as well , conditions on the right table of a left join should be placed inside the `ON` clause . 
Then, you can assume that when `st.id is not null` is met, `st_deleted = 0` is also true,  so you only need to check the first condition.

Comment: ehh , I check the mysql database, the st.deleted is 0.

Comment: @yunji It can be `NULL` because of the `LEFT JOIN` , not an actual `NULL` value. Did you run my query before posting a comment??